# How to setup CMake project to use PyTorch C++ API installed via Conda

Tags: c++, cmake, pytorch, conda

I have Miniconda3 on a Linux system (Ubuntu 22.04). The environment has Python 3.10 as well as a functioning (in Python) installation of PyTorch (installed following official instructions).

I would like to setup a CMake project that uses PyTorch C++ API. The reason is not important and also I am aware that it's beta (the official documentation states that), so instability and major changes are not excluded.

Currently I have this very minimal `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19) # or whatever version you use
project(PyTorch_Cpp_HelloWorld CXX)

set(PYTORCH_ROOT "/home/$ENV{USER}/miniconda/envs/ML/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch")
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${PYTORCH_ROOT}/share/cmake/Torch/")
find_package(Torch REQUIRED CONFIG)

...
# Add executable
# Link against PyTorch library
```

When I try to configure the project I'm getting error:

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:21 (message):   message called with
> incorrect number of arguments
>
> -- Could NOT find Protobuf (missing: Protobuf_LIBRARIES Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIR)
> -- Found Threads: TRUE   CMake Warning at /home/USER/miniconda/envs/ML/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/share/cmake/Caffe2/public/protobuf.cmake:88
> (message):   Protobuf cannot be found.  Depending on whether you are
> building Caffe2 or   a Caffe2 dependent library, the next warning /
> error will give you more   info. Call Stack (most recent call first):
> /home/USER/miniconda/envs/ML/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/share/cmake/Caffe2/Caffe2Config.cmake:56
> (include)
> /home/USER/miniconda/envs/ML/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/share/cmake/Torch/TorchConfig.cmake:68
> (find_package)   CMakeLists.txt:23 (find_package)
>
> CMake Error at
> /home/USER/miniconda/envs/ML/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/share/cmake/Caffe2/Caffe2Config.cmake:58
> (message):   Your installed Caffe2 version uses protobuf but the
> protobuf library cannot   be found.  Did you accidentally remove it,
> or have you set the right   CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH? If you do not have
> protobuf, you will need to install   protobuf and set the library path
> accordingly. Call Stack (most recent call first):
> /home/USER/miniconda/envs/ML/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/share/cmake/Torch/TorchConfig.cmake:68
> (find_package)   CMakeLists.txt:23 (find_package)

I installed `libprotobuf` (again via `conda`) but, while I can find the library files, I can't find any `*ProtobufConfig.cmake` or anything remotely related to protobuf and its CMake setup.

Before I go fight against wind mills I would like to ask here what the proper setup would be. I am guessing building from source is always an option, however this will pose a huge overhead on people, who I collaborate with.

Comment: Have you considered to download a pre-built libtorch and then just have it static in your project?

Comment: Good idea. I need to check PyTorch C++ license in regards to static linking though. A non-statically linked solution is still more then welcomed in case people do not want to do that or the license changes at some point in a way that makes it impossible (e.g. GPL as unlikely as such a thing is :D). Last but not least using Anaconda will ensure latest release is available (in case one wants to use it).

Comment: Minor terminology note: "Anaconda" is a Python distribution; "Conda" is a virtual environment and package management tool.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to using `conda`, I would suggest to just grab the pre-built library using the link https://download.pytorch.org/libtorch/nightly/cpu/libtorch-shared-with-deps-latest.zip Unzipping that will give you a folder `libtorch` which you can put next to your CMakeLists.txt. With that, all you need to have in your cmake (see [here](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/installing.html)) would be something like this:

```
project(example-app)

find_package(Torch REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${TORCH_CXX_FLAGS}")

add_executable(example-app example-app.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example-app "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")
set_property(TARGET example-app PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "libtorch")
```

Comment: I still prefer using PyTorch that is shipped with a popular package management system (such as `conda`). Many of colleagues use Anaconda (with `conda`) so distribution of my code should happen in a way that is easier for them to follow and understand. In addition downloading a separate version of the PyTorch that is already being used may create conflicts (I'm not sure how portable things are between different PyTorch versions but I just wasted a couple of days fighting with such an issue) not to mention cost extra storage (unzipped the library is approx. 700MB). I'll give you a +1 though. :)

Comment: My thought was that when you give your code to a CoWorker you can just put the libtorch folder along with it. You will need to make sure that you are all on the same libtorch version anyway, as they are not neccessarily compatible (you mentioned the beta status). You could also just integrate the downloading and extracting of the zip file into your CMakeLists

Comment: I will let you know if I find a way to use the `conda` packaged version though

Comment: @rbaleksandar As far as I can tell, the PyTorch that ships with `conda` is still built with `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0`, which makes it incompatible with other 3rd party libraries (such as `boost`). This has forced me to download directly a `cxx11-abi` enabled version. See [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/17492).

Comment: @dshin I found that out too. I solved my issue by directly downloading the binaries of libtorch using the `FetchContent` module in CMake. The only problem is that sometimes, if I screw up the build folder beyond repair (sadly not uncommon if I use CMake through Visual Studio 2017), I need to delete everything, which forces me to re-download this dependency. The CUDA version of libtorch is huge, the debug versions of CPU or CUDA are even worse. We are talking about up to 10GB. Unbelievable...

Answer (score 1):

Using this conda env:

```
name: pytorch_latest
channels:
  - pytorch
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - pytorch=1.11.0
  - torchvision
  - torchaudio
  - cpuonly
```

I copied the small example from [here](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/installing.html) and got it to run. The key was to set the correct library directories (both `torch` in `site-packages`, but also the `lib` folder of the environment). The cmake file is written so that the folders are automatically found :

**example-app.cpp**

```
#include <torch/torch.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  torch::Tensor tensor = torch::rand({2, 3});
  std::cout << tensor << std::endl;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0 FATAL_ERROR)
project(example-app)

#Add the torch library directory
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "$ENV{CONDA_PREFIX}/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch")

#This is needed to be able to find the mkl and other dependent libraries
link_directories("$ENV{CONDA_PREFIX}/lib")
set(ENV{MKLROOT} "$ENV{CONDA_PREFIX}/lib")
find_package(Torch REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${TORCH_CXX_FLAGS}")

add_executable(example-app example-app.cpp)

#We need to add pthread and omp manually here
target_link_libraries(example-app "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}" pthread omp)

set_property(TARGET example-app PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)
```

Exact environment (in case there are problems with reproducibility):

```
name: pytorch_latest
channels:
  - pytorch
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=conda_forge
  - _openmp_mutex=4.5=2_kmp_llvm
  - blas=2.115=mkl
  - blas-devel=3.9.0=15_linux64_mkl
  - brotlipy=0.7.0=py310h5764c6d_1004
  - bzip2=1.0.8=h7f98852_4
  - ca-certificates=2022.5.18.1=ha878542_0
  - certifi=2022.5.18.1=py310hff52083_0
  - cffi=1.15.0=py310h0fdd8cc_0
  - charset-normalizer=2.0.12=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - cpuonly=2.0=0
  - cryptography=37.0.1=py310h9ce1e76_0
  - ffmpeg=4.3=hf484d3e_0
  - freetype=2.10.4=h0708190_1
  - giflib=5.2.1=h36c2ea0_2
  - gmp=6.2.1=h58526e2_0
  - gnutls=3.6.13=h85f3911_1
  - idna=3.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jpeg=9e=h166bdaf_1
  - lame=3.100=h7f98852_1001
  - lcms2=2.12=hddcbb42_0
  - ld_impl_linux-64=2.36.1=hea4e1c9_2
  - lerc=3.0=h9c3ff4c_0
  - libblas=3.9.0=15_linux64_mkl
  - libcblas=3.9.0=15_linux64_mkl
  - libdeflate=1.10=h7f98852_0
  - libffi=3.4.2=h7f98852_5
  - libgcc-ng=12.1.0=h8d9b700_16
  - libgfortran-ng=12.1.0=h69a702a_16
  - libgfortran5=12.1.0=hdcd56e2_16
  - libiconv=1.17=h166bdaf_0
  - liblapack=3.9.0=15_linux64_mkl
  - liblapacke=3.9.0=15_linux64_mkl
  - libnsl=2.0.0=h7f98852_0
  - libpng=1.6.37=h21135ba_2
  - libstdcxx-ng=12.1.0=ha89aaad_16
  - libtiff=4.4.0=h0fcbabc_0
  - libuuid=2.32.1=h7f98852_1000
  - libuv=1.43.0=h7f98852_0
  - libwebp=1.2.2=h3452ae3_0
  - libwebp-base=1.2.2=h7f98852_1
  - libxcb=1.13=h7f98852_1004
  - libzlib=1.2.12=h166bdaf_0
  - llvm-openmp=14.0.4=he0ac6c6_0
  - lz4-c=1.9.3=h9c3ff4c_1
  - mkl=2022.1.0=h84fe81f_915
  - mkl-devel=2022.1.0=ha770c72_916
  - mkl-include=2022.1.0=h84fe81f_915
  - ncurses=6.3=h27087fc_1
  - nettle=3.6=he412f7d_0
  - numpy=1.22.4=py310h4ef5377_0
  - openh264=2.1.1=h780b84a_0
  - openjpeg=2.4.0=hb52868f_1
  - openssl=3.0.3=h166bdaf_0
  - pillow=9.1.1=py310he619898_1
  - pip=22.1.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pthread-stubs=0.4=h36c2ea0_1001
  - pycparser=2.21=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyopenssl=22.0.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pysocks=1.7.1=py310hff52083_5
  - python=3.10.4=h2660328_0_cpython
  - python_abi=3.10=2_cp310
  - pytorch=1.11.0=py3.10_cpu_0
  - pytorch-mutex=1.0=cpu
  - readline=8.1=h46c0cb4_0
  - requests=2.27.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - setuptools=62.3.2=py310hff52083_0
  - sqlite=3.38.5=h4ff8645_0
  - tbb=2021.5.0=h924138e_1
  - tk=8.6.12=h27826a3_0
  - torchaudio=0.11.0=py310_cpu
  - torchvision=0.12.0=py310_cpu
  - typing_extensions=4.2.0=pyha770c72_1
  - tzdata=2022a=h191b570_0
  - urllib3=1.26.9=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - wheel=0.37.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - xorg-libxau=1.0.9=h7f98852_0
  - xorg-libxdmcp=1.1.3=h7f98852_0
  - xz=5.2.5=h516909a_1
  - zlib=1.2.12=h166bdaf_0
  - zstd=1.5.2=h8a70e8d_1
```